# syntax to use binding expression inside href

Tags: angularjs

I have created a `nested accordian` bootstrap panel. On clicking the `parent(top most)` panel heading - dropdown works fine but on clicking the `child(sub panel heading)` panel heading-dropdown wont work. I am retriving panel contents(sub panel heading and body) using `angular $http.get rest api`.

In this case, i think i did a `mistake in syntax` while linking the panel heading and panel body with its `href and id` attribute values`( ng-href="{{productline_name}}" and id="{{productline_name}}" )`.

Below code is placed inside top most panel body to create nested panel

```
            <div class="panel-group col-lg-3" style="background-color:#505054;height:450px" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel" style="background-color:#505054;color:#C1C1C1;border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
                    <h6>Clear Filter</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" style="background-color:#505054;color:white;border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h6>
                        <div class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">PRODUCT</div>
                    </h6>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                               <li class="panel-title"><a ng-click="cfilter('all')"><h5>All Records</h5></a></li>
                               <li ng-repeat="pline in detpline" class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                                   <div class="panel" style="background-color:#505054;color:white;border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="plinefunc(pline.productline_name)">
                                        <h6>
                                        <div class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" ng-href="{{productline_name}}">{{pline.productline_name}}</div>
                                        </h6>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="{{productline_name}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li class="panel-title" ng-repeat="prd in detp"><a ng-click="cfilter(prd.product_name)"><h5>{{prd.product_name}}</h5></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can any one help in this? what is the correct syntax to use to link panel heading and panel body via binding expresion?

**Note**: I am using binding expression for linking only to avoid opening all other sub panel heading contents on-clicking one of the sub panel heading.

Comment: Make it ng-href and check

Comment: Update your code with **cfilter** function

Comment: could you put your code in a jsfiddle, this help to understand it

Comment: @suzo i used ng-href but no use

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón its of no use as i m using rest api - it wont work there with out credentials